# SQL - Group By based on optional flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a sales summary based on data with an optional "Elected" flag, which is user controlled. The flag determines whether or not to group items belonging to the same class of item.

If none of the items within a class have the Elected flag set to 1, the items appear as individual rows in the summary. If one or more items in a class has the flag set to 1, the items within that class get grouped based on the first item that has the flag set (lowest item_id).

For example:

```
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
| ItemId | Item | Class | Price | Qty | Elected |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
|    1   |  A1  |   1   | 25.00 |  2  |    1    |
|    2   |  A2  |   1   | 20.00 |  3  |    0    |
|    3   |  A3  |   1   | 25.00 |  4  |    0    |
|    4   |  B1  |   2   | 44.00 |  6  |    0    |
|    5   |  B2  |   2   | 41.00 |  7  |    0    |
|    6   |  C1  |   3   | 44.00 |  5  |    1    |
|    7   |  D1  |   4   | 32.00 |  9  |    0    |
|    8   |  D2  |   4   | 30.00 |  8  |    1    |
|    9   |  D3  |   4   | 30.00 |  2  |    1    |
+--------+------+-------+-------+-----+---------+
```

Should give the following summary:

```
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+-----+
| Class | Item | Total Price* | Unit Price^ | Qty |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+-----+
|   1   |  A1  |    70.00     |    35.00    |  2  |
|   2   |  B1  |    44.00     |     7.33    |  6  |
|   2   |  B2  |    41.00     |     5.85    |  7  |
|   3   |  C1  |    44.00     |     8.80    |  5  |
|   4   |  D2  |    92.00     |    11.50    |  8  |
+-------+------+--------------+-------------+-----+

* Total Price: SUM() within class
^ Unit Price: Total Price / Qty of elected item
```

In the above table, Class 1 is summarised via A1, Class 3 gets summarised via C1, and Class 4 gets summarised via D2. Class 2 does not get summarised at all and instead appears fully listed.

The query below is a hack via multiple self-joins, but it works. Is there a more efficient way to tackle the problem?

```
SELECT Sales.Class,
       coalesce(SalesWithFlagName.Item, SalesWithoutFlag._Item) 'Item',
       SUM(Sales.Price) 'Total Price',
       SUM(Sales.Price) / coalesce(SUM(Sales.Qty), SUM(SalesWithoutFlag._Qty)) 'Unit Price', /* Ignore possible Div0 error */
       COALESCE(SUM(Sales.Qty), SUM(SalesWithoutFlag._Qty)) 'Qty'
FROM   Sales

/* Class with at least one flag set: Get first item with flag */
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Class _Class,
         Elected _Elected,
         MIN(ItemId) _ItemId
  FROM   Sales

  GROUP BY Class, Elected
) AS SalesWithFlag ON (
  Sales.ItemId = SalesWithFlag._ItemId
  AND Sales.Elected = 1
)

/* Get item name from first Left Join */
LEFT JOIN Sales SalesWithFlagName ON (
  SalesWithFlag._ItemId IS NOT NULL
  AND SalesWithFlag._ItemId = SalesWithFlagName.ItemId
)

/* Class with at least flag not set: Get all items without flag */
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Class _Class,
         ItemId _ItemId,
         Item   _Item,
         Qty    _Qty
  FROM   Sales s2

  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Sales s3 WHERE s3.Elected = 1 AND s2.Class = s3.Class)

  GROUP BY Class, ItemId, Item, Qty

) AS SalesWithoutFlag ON (
  Sales.ItemId = SalesWithoutFlag._ItemId
  AND Sales.Elected = 0
)

WHERE SalesWithFlag._ItemId IS NOT NULL 
   OR SalesWithoutFlag._ItemId IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY Sales.Class,
         COALESCE(SalesWithFlagName.Item, SalesWithoutFlag._Item)
```

Comment: You have to explain what `sumarize` means. I think class 3 isnt sumarize because follow same pattern as class 2.

Comment: Also you need to explain what is the first item with Elected. You mean the one with smaller `item_id` ?

Comment: Thank you, Class 3 should have had the flag set to 1. Yes, by first I meant the one with the lowest item_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both individual rows and aggregates, so this is a task for a `Group Sum` and some additional logic:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT *,
      -- either the individual Price or the Group Sum
      CASE
        WHEN Elected = 1 
          THEN SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Class) 
        ELSE Price 
      END AS TotalPrice,
      -- is there any Elected = 1 within the Class?
      MAX(Elected) OVER (PARTITION BY Class) AS maxElected,
      -- Find the first row with Elected = 1
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Elected DESC, ItemId) AS rn
   FROM Sales
 )
SELECT
   class,
   Item,
   TotalPrice,
   TotalPrice / Qty AS UnitPrice,
   QTy
FROM cte
WHERE maxElected = 0 -- no Elected = 1
   OR rn = 1         -- first row with Elected = 1
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff640/1)

Comment: Pretty awesome, and the comments make it clear. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `SUM` of the price of each Class as a seperate entity, then join them up to your conditional query and also do the same for classes without a flag, but instead union them to the select statement:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Class, SUM(Price) as [Total Price]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Class)
, CTE2 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Class 
FROM Table1 AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Class FROM Table1 AS B WHERE A.Class=B.Class AND Elected = 1))
, CTE3 AS (
SELECT A.Class, A.ItemID, A.Item, B.[Total Price], ROUND(CAST(B.[Total Price] AS FLOAT) / Qty, 2) AS [Unit Price], Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Class ORDER BY A.ItemID ASC) AS RN
FROM Table1 AS A
JOIN CTE AS B
ON A.Class=B.Class
WHERE A.Elected = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Class, ItemId, Item, Price, ROUND(CAST(Price AS FLOAT) / Qty, 2), Qty, 1
FROM Table1
WHERE Class IN (SELECT Class FROM CTE2))
SELECT Class, Item, [Total Price], CAST([Unit Price] AS NUMERIC(36,2)) AS [Unit Price], Qty 
FROM CTE3
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Class, Item
```

Comment: Your answer leaves out Class 2 (no item has flag set), and gives two results for Class 4 (multiple items with flag).

Comment: So what determines that D2 is the correct flag to use and not D3?

Comment: D2 has the lowest item_id. I'll update the question with this info since it had already been asked by @Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect these requirements. Sorry to say, it's a very strange model, but if it works for you....

Comment: This version is working, thank you. Yes it is strange, the flag is being added now and we need to ensure backwards compatibility for the summary (hence it being optional).

Answer (score 0):

You can select for each class min itemid which is elected and then it is simple grouping:

```
;with cte as(select *, (select isnull(min(itemid), t1.itemid) 
                         from t t2 
                         where t2.class = t1.class and t2.elected = 1) as parentid
              from t t1)
select p.itemid, 
       p.item,
       p.class, 
       p.qty, 
       sum(c.price) as price,
       sum(c.price) / p.qty as unitprice
from cte c
join cte p on c.parentid = p.itemid
group by p.itemid, p.item, p.class, p.qty
```

Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7aac9/6

Comment: Working, seems less efficient than @dnoeth 's answer though, based on the test results of both your fiddles